# Why is my slicer not filtering values correctly for me for 2 different matrix?

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax, entity-relationship

[*Rough Overview of the Relationship between the tables that I am using*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvK0L.png)

Chicken feet on both ends of the line means Many to many relationship, and I have used arrows to show the filtering.
I have a matrix that used the column [Last PM Date] from [PM CHECKLIST] and another matrix that uses the [BRB date] from SP_USED. However, when I use the [Date] column from the Date table as a field in my slicer, and I select a range, for instance, January 2021 - Mar 2021, I will see dates from beyond my selected range in both my matrix, what could be the reason behind this?

Comment: You didn't show the dates column in the top two tables in your image, what's the correlation of these dates to the one in the bottom table? Are they the same? Probably not. What happens when you add the date column from the bottom table to your matrix?